# How can I concatenate a text capitalized by a foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenation, capitalize

```
using System;

class Program{
  public static void Main (string[] args){
    string Text = "the sentence which each word must be capitalized";
    string[] WordArray = new string[8];

    foreach (string Word in Text.Split(' ')){
      string CapitalizedFirstLetter = Word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
      string RestOfWord = Word.Substring(1, Word.Length-1);
      string ConcatenatedWord = string.Concat(CapitalizedFirstLetter, RestOfWord);
    }
  }
}
```

I was planning to capitalize each words and concatenate it again but, I cannot concatenate it.
How should I concatenate it?

Comment: `StringBuilder`, or add it to a `List<string>` and use `string.Join`.

Comment: Can you explain what's stopping you from concatenating them? Even `string newString = aString + bString;` is valid C#, so I don't understand what the problem is at the most basic level.

Comment: You've already initialized `string[] WordArray`, why don't you add the `ConcatentatedWord` to the array at the appropriate index, then `string.Join` the array once your `foreach` loop is done?

Comment: you are clearing ConcatenatedWord  In each loop (as you define it again and again with each word and of course you also didn,t concatenate to any phrase at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
string text = "the sentence which each word must be capitalized";

var words = text.Split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) words[i] =  
Char.ToUpper(words[i][0]).ToString()+words[i].Substring(1);

text = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, you can do it like this:

```
string Text = "the sentence which each word must be capitalized";
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Text));
```

Output:

```
The Sentence Which Each Word Must Be Capitalized
```

Comment: Unfortunately `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` is a _very blunt instrument_ which does not respect the fact that _stop-words_ (like "a", "the", "in", etc) should _not_ be capitalized when rendered in title-case.

Comment: @scor4er That a good note to know for reference, but the code and text of the original question doesn't respect stop-words either.

Comment: @Dai agree, but in this case, I think the op was looking for exactly this behavior

Answer (score 0):

A slightly inelegant way is to track all the words as you go in a list and then join at the end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program{
  public static void Main (string[] args){
    string Text = "the sentence which each word must be capitalized";
    string[] WordArray = new string[8];    //Unused
    List<string> WordsCapitalized = new(); //New line

    foreach (string Word in Text.Split(' ')){
      string CapitalizedFirstLetter = Word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
      string RestOfWord = Word.Substring(1, Word.Length-1);
      string ConcatenatedWord = string.Concat(CapitalizedFirstLetter, RestOfWord);
      WordsCapitalized.Add(ConcatenatedWord); //new line
    }

    string FinalString = String.Join(" ", WordsCapitalized); //" " is delimiter between words
  }
}
```

This is building off the code you posted, and just to show a straightforward way of doing it. It's not necessarily how I would approach this from scratch. At a minimum, I would clean it up and reduce the number of variables in this approach if it were my code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *regular expressions*:

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string Text = "the sentence which (each!) word must BE capitalized";

 string result = Regex.Replace(Text, 
   @"\b\p{Ll}\p{L}*\b",
    match => {
      string word = match.Value;

      //TODO: Some logic if we want to capitalize the word
      // if (...) return word; 

      return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word);  
    }
 );

 Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
The Sentence Which (Each!) Word Must BE Capitalized
```

note, that `BE` is preserved and `(each!)` is converted into `(Each!)`

**Pattern explained:**

```
 \b     - word boundary 
 \p{Ll} - low case letter
 \p{L}* - zero or more letters
 \b     - word boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ufuk

If you expect this output "The Sentence Which Each Word Must Be Capitalized". Then your code is looks good. You have already done 95% work. Already splitting with capitalized but you need to  store them in some place.
So I have created a string variable to store them. Only two lines I have written.

```
class Program{
  public static void Main (string[] args){
    string Text = "the sentence which each word must be capitalized";
    string outputText="";

    foreach (string Word in Text.Split(' ')){
      string CapitalizedFirstLetter = Word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
      string RestOfWord = Word.Substring(1, Word.Length-1);
      string ConcatenatedWord = string.Concat(CapitalizedFirstLetter, RestOfWord);
      outputText = outputText + " " + ConcatenatedWord ;
    }
  }
}
```